# How do I reset the jQuery traversal stack to load the elements in order each time?

Tags: jquery, traversal

The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u5wXm/2/) on jsFiddle.

If you run the example and hit the next button until you get to the last page. You will see that image #10 loads and is visible and then it only loads image #7, #8 and #9. I also logged it in the console, so you can see that it loads #10, #7, #8, #9 in that order.

I hope this makes sense. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's your prependTo call that's causing the elements to jump around. Try changing the list click() function to this:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('ul').find('li:not(.selected)').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

That should get you pretty close.

Comment: That click event actually never gets called if you just hit the next button. I tried adding your code and it's still doing the exact same thing. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're attempting. If I only hit the Next button I never see anything out of order. Do you?

Comment: If you look at the [console](http://i51.tinypic.com/53mq2b.jpg), on the last next click, it loads image #10 then #7, #8, #9. The issue being that #10 shows up on the screen first and then gets bumped over by the others, I want them all to show up at the same time.